# TwitterBootstrap + mvc, how to pass dynamic width to boostrap .less class

Tags: less

i am using TwitterBootstrap and i want to pass button width dynamic..like below code

[image: this is my mvc(view) page where i give/set class name]

[image: this is buttons.less file]

[image: this is varible.less file]

I want to pass **"@wth"** value **Dynamically** from client side(from view(MVC)).
Right now it's coming**Statically** on **varibles.less** file....But i want to pass directly from view(MVC).

> so, what is the Best Solution ?

Comment: I'm curious - why do you paste *images of code* when you could just paste *code*?

Comment: generally i am not using stack ....so, i had not much idea & awareness of the code's plus point than image..

Answer (score 1):

Although it gives the impression of being able to do dynamic things if you use less.js in the browser, those styles are all compiled into CSS files, and have fixed values by the time they are applied to your html. So **you can't change values of Less variables after the page loads**.

If you need to change the width of a button dynamically based on a few pre-set sizes, I'd say you should add classes to your css (small, medium, large, etc.), and then dynamically add that class to your CSS via Jquery's [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) method.

If you need to set the width directly, I'd use Jquery's [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method.

If you're going to be doing a lot of this sort of thing, you may want to look into using a data-binding library that can bind a Javascript object to your html styles, such as [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/).

Comment: Hi Bro, thx for reply...i am familiar with knockout + jquery. but i want to make some new thing with "TwitterBootstrap". so, have u any idea how can i make or provide me links or code?...it should be helpful to me.

Comment: There are lots of good exmaples on the Bootstrap site: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/getting-started.html#examples

Comment: i know that...i an using bootstrap...but my question is... "CAN  I PASS CSS VALUE DYNAMIC?"...plz see my question again....THX

Comment: As I stated in my answer, you can't change the values of those variables after the page loads. LESS is not intended to be used this way.